# how to calculate position in <translate> tag in android animation?

Tags: android, animation

I am new to android animation and i've been playing with animation in android.
But one thing i just don't get it?
how to set position in  tag.
My question is what 50%p means?
Suppose I have a button at some place 1/3 of the top. now i want to move it to bottom of the layout.then move to left bottom then at the center of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

the doc says

> Float or percentage. Starting X/Y offset. Expressed either: in pixels relative to the normal position (such as "5"), in percentage relative to the element width (such as "5%"), or in percentage relative to the parent width (such as "5%p").

once see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#translate-element) doc. This will help you to solve your issue.